# Does the POM file configuration overwrite the default settings of Spring Tool Suite configuration?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, spring-tool-suite, eclipse-jee

After checking this link [No Compiler is provided in this environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177441/java-compiler-setting-is-resetting-in-sts-this-is-the-errorno-compiler-is-pro)
I observed that POM file configuration is overwriting STS default settings. This might be the reason whenever project is run on server, it is generating the error as mentioned in above link. This might be the code which is overwriting the STS default configuration:

```
<plugin>  
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>              
    <configuration>  
        <source>${jdk.version}</source>  
        <target>${jdk.version}</target>  
    </configuration>  
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of the Maven support in Eclipse (which is also included in STS). It automatically maps your JDK version setting in your pom file to the compiler settings in Eclipse/STS. Otherwise you would end up having the IDE compile for a different JDK version than your Maven build - which would be a bit strange.